# Can't Change Row Heights of Cells - Have 2 Prototype Cells

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitableview

I have a TableView with 2 prototype cells in it. I want one of them to be static (call it header cell), and the other one to be dynamic (call it description cell).

So I set TableView cell to Dynamic Prototypes and 2 for prototypes cells). *I have also set up the TableView and increased prototype cells; and put dummy data for seeing them working.*

However, whatever I have done I couldn't resize the Header cell.

- First, in Storyboard, I tried changing Row Height for the Header Cell (and I ticked the 'Custom'). It seems like changing the height of the row in the Storyboard; in fact it doesn't after the build.
- Secondly, this width and height bit seems disabled.

[image]

- It's also same for the `Content View` just under the `Header Cell`. Width & Height adjusting part is disabled.

By the way, everything is same for the `Description Cell`. I tried adding it a row height,  and it seems like changing in the Storyboard, but after build, no luck. It is just behaving by itself.

I should also highlight that it's giving a bit more room for `Description Cell` which I return `cell.textLabel?.text = "BlaBla"` (so it has to write the text itself); but for the other cell where I am dragging/dropping on Storyboard, it just squeezes the height.

What may I be doing wrong? What do you think do I miss?

---

**Edit:** (I have a Navigation Bar at the top)

- How it looks on Simulator:

[image]

- How it looks on Storyboard:

[image]

---

As you can see it's narrowing the `Header Cell` (so messing the design), and increasing the height of `Description Cell` randomly.

If I can do it with `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, how should I use this approach for giving different height to 2 prototypes cells. (I want to have `Header Cell` to be static row height, but `Description - Dynamic`, or at least not identical height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to implement `- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view's delegate and return the height you'd like for each row.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 100
    }
    return 44
}
```

Comment: How can I use it when I have multiple prototype cells? Wouldn't `return 44` for example affect both cells?

Comment: @senty you should sent both `heightForHeaderInSection` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @senty No. You just need two returns. I've updated the answer to show what that might look like.

Comment: Oh, totally missed `heightForHeaderInSection`. Thanks a lot!